# Codename One - Downloading txt file from URL not working in iOS

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have an app that downloads a txt file from a URL, saves it to storage, and then I do some parsing on it. On Android and the simulator for iOS, the behavior is as expected and works fine. On the actual iphone, the stream from the URL is blank.

```
public void getDailyMTX() {
        String mtxURL = "https://someURLhere.com/file.txt";
        FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        Util.downloadUrlToStorage(mtxURL, fileName, true);

        try {
              InputStream is = fs.openInputStream(fileName);
              s = Util.readToString(is, "UTF-8");
              Dialog.show("downloaded file", s, "OK", 
              null);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
              // handle exception
            }
      }
```

I put the Dialog.show() in there for debugging purposes to try to help me see what is going on. The dialog pops up and the body of it is blank. I'm pretty confused because on earlier versions of my app this code was working. Not sure what I've screwed up. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the logs for any errors? Is the URL using a valid certificate (complying with ATS rules)? Is it actually valid UTF-8?

Comment: Yeah, there's not any errors posted on the logs. The file is encoded in UTF-8. I've tried to download a couple of other files just to see if it was the file itself but its the same result. I'll look more into the ATS requirements - I'll admit, I'm quite weak in my knowledge in that area. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You are downloading the file to **Storage**, but you are trying to read from **FileSystemStorage**.  These are two different things.  On some platforms, it stores **Storage** in the file system, which is why this might work by some luck in some platforms.  But you can't count on this.

If you want to use FileSystemStorage, then use [Util.downloadUrlToFile](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html#downloadUrlToFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-) for the download.  If you want to use Storage, then use [Storage.createInputStream](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html#createInputStream-java.lang.String-) to read the file.